# Set a date to a month not from the current date using moment

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I need to set the date to month “01 April” of that current year  so that at a later stage I can calculate the number of days from  the current date. Is this the ideal way to do it?

```
let year = moment().year();
let newDt = moment(year).add(3, 'months').format('MM-DD-YYYY') // Just set the date to 1st April
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple with moment. Just do `moment().date(1).month(3)`

Edit : I have added a full example

```js
const aprilFirst = moment().date(1).month(3);
alert('Date difference is ' + moment().diff(aprilFirst, 'days') + ' days');
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```